# How to programmatically shutdown remaining mapreduce splits once job is done

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a newbie to hadoop/yarn/mapreduce.

I'm trying to index documents into ElasticSearch from Cassandra using MapReduce job. I'm seeing around 700 splits but all my documents are indexed by the 16th split (grepped the userlogs). Is there any way to programmatically (Java) gracefully shutdown the remaining tasks once there are no more documents to index?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the task id and input split for the mapper using below code in your map method.

```
JobConf.get("mapred.task.id");

FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName()
```

Using above filename you will get the file name of input split using which  you can kill all tasks which you dont need to execute.

**Please check if the job completes successfully after killing few map tasks,** I believe job should fail. Instead of killing map tasks I think it would be better idea to input only the files that you need to index for mapreduce program.